# I want to get tor-browser-bundle to run on an RPi2 B. What OS can I use? What are the steps?

Tags: debian, pi-2, ubuntu, berryboot

I have been trying for months to get tor-browser-bundle TBB to run on my RPI2.
My knowlege of linux is very limited.
I have tried to download from Torproject and cannot get it to run.
I have tried in most of the oses in NOOBS and BERRYBOOT.
I do not know how to get Straight DEBIAN to run on the RIP2.
I have tried to get Tor-Launcher to run and load it for me. 
I would love for someone knowlegable to get TOR-BROWSER to run on a rpi2 and tell me (and the rest of the world) how it is done.
It might require knowlege of where to run it.
It might require re- compiling it for a particular version of linux. 
I would consider giving an rpi2 to someone who needs it to build TBB on. 
(There seems to be another program that seems to be named TBB)
Anyway I am short of knowlege to do this task myself after several months of looking on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Glenn, no need to reinvent the wheel!

Courtesy of Adafruit !

https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor

[image: No need to reinvent the wheel !]

Comment: Great! - but could you please add the tutorial into your answer? Links often go dead and if it does this answer will become useless...

Answer (score 0):

I just asked Google and there's a plethera of guides on how to setup Tor on RPi proxy; the *[best](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi)* constructed one has been linked and to [skip](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor) ahead to where they get into installation and configuration. To get the RPi's local browser to also rout through Tor is browser spicific so search for `<browser name> how to connect to Tor` for the browser you wish to use on the RPi itself.